# How to call wrapper Class Public variable in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am writing one test class in which i have test the Selected Orders.

Here is my Main Class Code Portion which is not getting covered.

==Main Class code Portion======

```
    for(Orderc cOrd: orderlist) {
    if(cOrd.selected == true) {
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req.setComments(Comments);
        req.setAction('Approve');
        Id workItemId = getWorkItemId(cord.ord.id); 
        // submit the approval request for processing
        if(workItemId == null){
            cord.ord.addError('Error Occured');
        }
    }
}
```

Now here I am Not able to access the Selected Varibale which is in Wrapper Class As a Boolean Variable.

=====Wrapper Class code====

```
@TestVisible public class Orderc{
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
}
```

=====Test class code that i am tryinhg====

```
public class Br_MassOrderApprovalTest {
    public static testMethod void VerifyOrders() {
        Br_OrderwrapperClassController foo  = new Br_OrderwrapperClassController();
        Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc  obj = new Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc();   
        //problem area: 
        obj .selected='true';
    }
}
```

> error: Variable does not exist:
> Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc.selected

Can anyone please suggest, thanks.

Comment: First, why you set a string value (`'true'`) to your Boolean property?

Answer (score 2):

Your selected variable is a atributte, you need instance your order and after that you init soul variable.

**Example Test Code EDITED**

```
    public static testMethod void VerifyOrders() {

    Br_OrderwrapperClassController controller  = new Br_OrderwrapperClassController();
    controller.orderList = new List<Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc>();

    Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc newOrderc = new Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc();
    newOrderc.selected = true;

    controller.orderList.add(newOrderc);
}
```

Comment: Hi Torsen, thanks for your prompt reply...In my main class i have property set as public List<Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc> Orderc{get; set;} so its giving me error as : Illegal assignment from Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc to List&lt;Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc&gt; uopn using your code, any idea..

Comment: i edit my response. give me a second

Comment: Can you add more code of your clases??

Comment: Hi Torsen i have Edited my code, let me know if you have any Questions or confusion in the Requirement..

Comment: Hi Prateek Jain, i edited my  response. I init the order list and I add a order with selected = true.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting your variable because you're calling a method that is defined at the instance level at the class level. The setter for "selected" needs to be called on an INSTANCE of your inner class `Orderc`.

Where in your controller do you use the `Orderc` class? Probably, the code you need to write is something like

```
public class Br_MassOrderApprovalTest {
  public static testMethod void VerifyOrders() {
    Br_OrderwrapperClassController foo  = new Br_OrderwrapperClassController();
    foo.orderc.selected='true';
  }
}
```

Assuming that your controller `foo` has an `orderc` property that returns an instance of `Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc`.

Comment: Hi Christian , thanks for writing back , even after calling it like foo.orderc.selected='true' and setting Property in foo..it given : Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List&lt;Br_OrderwrapperClassController.Orderc&gt; error, please help..

Answer (score 1):

The apex properties available inside of an inner class will be accessible by a property in the outer class.

```
public class Br_MassOrderApprovalTest {
    public static testMethod void VerifyOrders() {
        Br_OrderwrapperClassController foo = new Br_OrderwrapperClassController();
        foo.c0rd.selected=true;
    }
}
```

The property in outer class named c0rd should be used to access the property in the inner class.

Hope it helps.